# How to fix error message when running 2SLS in R?

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to run a 2SLS but the following error message occurs: "Error in solve.default(vcov.hyp) :system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.63951e-18"

The actual OLS works and R is providing results. But for the 2SLS, I don't get any results.

My code so far:

```
#OLS

ols_reg <- lm(Y1 ~ Y2 + X1)
summary(ols_reg)

#2SLS

iv_reg = ivreg(Y1 ~ Y2 + X1 | X1 + X2)
summary(iv_reg)
```

I have seen a other answer on this problem, but it refers to covariate matrix and not 2SLS directly.
I tried the following things to correct the error:

- removed all missing values / infinite values and NAs
- I checked for multi-collinearity: I identified a high correlation between two variables (-0.66519), so I removed one of the variable. The error still remains though and I also need to include both variables in my model.
- it is not a problem of overfitting, since I have roughly 33,000 observation and I have 10 variables to include in the model.
- I tried dividing the highest values of one variable by 1000 in order to not have too high values. But that did not work either.

I found that the problem is that R sees the matrix as computationally singular, which means that it is almost 0 and R can only calculate up to a certain number. I read that it would be possible to raise the tolerance in order for R to calculate the matrix, eventhough it is very close to zero. But I haven't found the solution for doing this.

Is there anything else I could do?
So far, I have used the ivreg function, but I am happy to calculate the 2SLS model manually, if that would be the only option.